# Trigger an email if a condition is met using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to trigger an email if a condition is true using Python. Below is a part of the script that I am using. Though it doesn't throw any error but doesn't trigger the email as well when the 1st condition is met.

```
....if text>content1:
    o365_auth = ('susername.com.com', 'pwd')
    m = Message(auth=o365_auth)
    m.setRecipients('username.com','ausername.com.com')
    m.setSubject('Data found.')
    m.setBody('New Data found.')
    m.sendMessage()
elif text==content1:
    print("NO Data found for today.")
else:
    print("Process Complete")
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minor tweak as highlighted resolved the issue.  It wasn't allowing to use more than one recipients.

```
 ....if text>content1:
        o365_auth = ('susername.com.com', 'pwd')
        m = Message(auth=o365_auth)
        receipts = ['username.com', 'ausername.com.com']# Build a list of recepients and used the same in below code.
        #m.setRecipients('username.com','ausername.com.com') # Removed this piece
        m.setRecipients(receipts) 
        m.setSubject('Data found.')
        m.setBody('New Data found.')
        m.sendMessage()
    elif text==content1:
        print("NO Data found for today.")
    else:
        print("Process Complete")
```